# Is $\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{111}+\frac{1}{1111}+\cdots$ an irrational number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Obviously:

$$\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{1000}+\cdots=0.1111\dots=\frac{1}{9}$$

is a rational number.

Now, if we make terms with demoninators in the form:

$$q_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} 10^k$$

Then the sum will be:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{q_n}=\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{111}+\frac{1}{1111}+\cdots=0.1009181908362007\dots$$

The decimal expansion of this number appears to be non-periodic.

> How can we prove/disprove that this number is irrational?

*Edit*

This number is at OEIS: http://oeis.org/A065444

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If we define the "Lambert series"
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1-x^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1/x)^n-1},
$$
then since $q_n = (10^{n+1}-1)/9$, your number is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{q_n} = 9f(\tfrac1{10})-1.
$$
Chowla proved in 1947 that $f(\frac1{10})$ is irrational, and hence so is your number. You can find a proof in [this 1948 paper of Erdös](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1948-04.pdf).

(Interesting side note: we also have
$$
f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \tau(m)x^m,
$$
where $\tau(m)$ is the number of positive divisors of $m$.)

Comment: Is it only irrational or even transcendental?

Comment: @MrYouMath that's probably unknown. Proving numbers are transcendental is really hard

Comment: One could search MathSciNet or Google Scholar for "Lambert series transcendental" to see if anyone's made progress on that question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer to the question of irrationality. This a piece of information about an interesting closed form of the series.

$$q_n=\sum_{k=0}^n 10^k = \frac{10^{n+1}-1}{9}$$
$q_0=1\quad;\quad q_1=11\quad;\quad q_2=111\quad...$

$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{q_n}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{111}+... \quad$ ($m+1$ terms).

$$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{q_n}=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{9}{10^{n+1}-1}=
\frac{9}{\ln(10)}\left(\psi_{10}(m+2)-\psi_{10}(1)\right)-9(m+1)$$
$\psi_q(x)$ is the q-digamma function. The leading terms of the asymptotic series are:
$$\psi_{10}(x)\sim (x-\frac{1}{2})\ln(10)-\ln(9)$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{q_n}\sim
\frac{9}{\ln(10)}\left( (m+2-\frac{1}{2})\ln(10)-\ln(9)-\psi_{10}(1)\right)-9(m+1)$$

After simplification :
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{q_n}=\frac{9}{2}
-\frac{9}{\ln(10)}\left( \ln(9)+\psi_{10}(1)\right)$$
$\psi_{10}(1)\simeq-1.32759401026424207 $

$\frac{9}{2}
-\frac{9}{\ln(10)}\left( \ln(9)+\psi_{10}(1)\right)\simeq 1.100918190836200736 $

Note that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{q_n}$ includes the first term$=1$